# Simple SAML Successhandler

Tags: spring-security, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

We are converting the project from LDAP authentication to simple SAML authentication. We have our own validation ("userValidation") which we called in the successhandler method in the LDAP authentication( sample code below). We are facing issues with converting this validation method to  simple SAML security-context.xml file. Could you help me how to do it in SAML with this validation? Also provide the solution equivalent in XML based developement.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

   http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().successHandler(userValidation)
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this the structure for you configuration in spring security i hope it help you  for your AuthenticationSuccuessHandler you need to put in a class then refer to it

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import javax.sql.DataSource ;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    //Pour l'authentification des Utilisateur de Table Utilisateur
@Autowired
Securityhandler Myauthen  ;


@Autowired  
public void GlobalConfig(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth,DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
auth.jdbcAuthentication()
    .dataSource(dataSource) 
    .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT  \"Pseudo\" AS principal , \"Password\" AS  credentials , true FROM \"UTILISATEUR\" WHERE \"Pseudo\" =  ? ")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT  u.\"Pseudo\" AS principal , r.role as role  FROM \"UTILISATEUR\" u ,\"Role\" r where u.id_role=r.id_role AND \"Pseudo\" = ?  ")
                .rolePrefix("_ROLE");
}
    //ne pas appliqué la securité sur les ressources 
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
    .antMatchers("/bootstrap/**","/css/**");

}
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http

    .csrf().disable()   
    .authorizeRequests()

    .anyRequest()   
        .authenticated()        
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .successHandler(Myauthen);

}

}
```